# Play an mp3 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, mp3

### What I have

An *mp3* file, 16kHz, 1 channel. Read like:

```
[data,Fs] = audioread('file.mp3');
```

This file is playable in Windows Media Player i.e., and works fine.

### What I want

To play it inside matlab. After reading it, I've tried to play it, like:

```
soundsc(data);
```

However, it doesn't sound even near to how it should (neither using **sound** instead of **soundsc**).

### The Problem then is..

How can I play this mp3 vector inside matlab? Is it even possible? Or do I need to convert it to other format so I can work with it? (wav I guess?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the sample frequency. You need

```
soundsc(data, Fs)
```

If not present, the `Fs` argument defaults to 8192 Hz, which is not the correct one.

Also, note that if you don't need scaling you can use

```
sound(data, Fs)
```

which will run a little faster.